# Python inverse diff function for multivariate time series

Tags: python, time-series, diff, difference

I’ve been working through this for a couple hours without any luck and decided to ask the community for help. I was able to difference the series through the `diff()` function and also manually differencing, now I am trying to inverse the `diff()` function in python for a multivariate time series.

This code doesn’t inverse the difference for row 1 of the original dataframe. It basically inverse and shifted the values up a row.

```
#manually compute difference

cols = df.columns
diff_df = []
for col in cols:    
    diff_results = df[col] - df[col].shift(1)
    diff_results = diff_results.fillna(0) 
    diff_df.append(diff_results)
diff_df_res = pd.concat(diff_df, axis=1)



#reverse difference
cols = df.columns
diff_df = []
for col in cols:
    diff_results = df[col] + diff_df_res[col].shift(-1)
    diff_df.append(diff_results)
diff_df_res2 = pd.concat(diff_df, axis=1)
```

```
df:
               x1     x2    x3
2018-01-01  1336.0  184.0  17.0
2018-02-01  1204.0  157.0  15.0
2018-03-01  1603.0  208.0  25.0
2018-04-01  1287.0  187.0  21.0
2018-05-01  1412.0  220.0  28.0


diff_df_res:
               x1    x2    x3
2018-01-01    0.0   0.0   0.0
2018-02-01 -132.0 -27.0  -2.0
2018-03-01  399.0  51.0  10.0
2018-04-01 -316.0 -21.0  -4.0
2018-05-01  125.0  33.0   7.0


diff_df_res2:
                x1     x2    x3
2018-01-01  1204.0  157.0  15.0
2018-02-01  1603.0  208.0  25.0
2018-03-01  1287.0  187.0  21.0
2018-04-01  1412.0  220.0  28.0
2018-05-01     NaN    NaN   NaN
'''
```

Comment: Can you please share your input data and the desired output?

Comment: I added screenshots of the data frames. The desired output is for the inverse (diff_df_res2) to look like the original dataframe (df)

Comment: Thank you, although it is considered good to post data in a textual form in order to help people answer your question quicker by not making them manually copy the data from the screenshots. Should be fairly easy for you since it seems you're using Jupyter Notebook. Just type `print(df)` and copy the result.

Comment: Added the copies.

Comment: Tbh I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve here with the "reverse" thing. Are you trying to get the initial data frame? Why not just take the `df` you started with?

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm reading your intentions right, by "reverse difference" do you mean the difference from the other direction? that is, the same as `diff_df_res` only to the other direction? or are you trying to reconstruct the original data from the difference?